# Webmobile - Display 3 select boxes at the same time !

Tags: html, iphone, forms, select

I have a mobile website (mainly iPhone, but Android and others too..) with a simple form. It contains three select boxes for the day, the month and the year. The iPhone automatically displays a pretty nice wheel for each one of the select boxes, but only one at the same time.

Is there an easy way to display the 3 wheels (corresponding to the 3 form fields) at the same time, to get kind of a "triple-wheel" which would make the date picking easier, faster, and even sexier \o/

Frenchly ^^

Julien L

Answer (score 0):

You might look at emulating [`UIDatePicker`](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2010/02/how-to-use-uidatepicker-from-uikit-in-iphone-programming-2/) with HTML.

Comment: That's exactly how I want it to be! If someone knows an easy way to do it, that would be amazing!!! :D